# Integration using Integral reduction for csc

Tags: calculus, integration

To solve the integral:
$$\int \csc(x)^4 $$
Using the integral reduction formula for csc and got:
$$-\frac{1}{3} \cot(x)\csc^2(x)-\frac{2}{3}\cot(x)+C$$
However, plugging the same integral into a calculator the solution appeared to be
$$-\frac{1}{3} \cos(x)\csc^3(x)-\frac{2}{3}\cot(x)+C$$

Was there anything wrong with the first solution, or is there another integral reduction formula for $\csc$?

Comment: Your answers are equivalent: $\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \cos(x)\csc(x)$. So you're both correct. Well done!

Comment: $\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$

Answer (score 6):

Both are same, $\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \cos x \csc x$.

So,

$\cot x \csc^2 x = \cos x \csc^3 x$